# Getting next two indexes regardless of current index

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create a mock rock, paper, scissors game with each name having two enemies, so I must be able to grab the values of all the names regardless of the position.

Say I am given this list:

```
names = ["Kings", "Queens", "Jacks", "Jokers", "Masons", "Warriors", "Soldiers"]
```

And I am trying to use the logic with the indexes being the values and would gather the next two values of the indexes. Each index would return the these values.

```
0 - 1, 2
1 - 2, 3
2 - 3, 4
3 - 4, 5
4 - 5, 6
5 - 6, 0
6 - 0, 1
```

So 'Warriors' will have the enemies of: Soldiers and Kings

Below being my current implementation:

```
def state_to_text(self): 
    names = ["Kings", "Queens", "Jacks", "Jokers", "Masons", "Warriors", "Soldiers"]
    if self.state == 0:
        return str(names[1], names[2])
    if self.state == 1:
        return str(names[2], names[3])
    if self.state == 2:
        return str(names[3], names[4])
    if self.state == 3:
        return str(names[4], names[5])
    if self.state == 4:
        return str(names[5], names[6])
    if self.state == 5:
        return str(names[6], names[1])
    if self.state == 6:
        return str(names[0], names[1])
```

Thank you.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic

Comment: Uh... `num`, `(num+1)%len(names)`, and `(num+2)%len(names)`?

Comment: I don't really understand the question.  I probably would if you posted a minimal example with the hard-coded solution you do not like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comment said you can use modular arithmetic:

```
def state_to_text(self): 
    names = ["Kings", "Queens", "Jacks", "Jokers", "Masons", "Warriors", "Soldiers"]
    names_length = len(names) 
    return str(names[(self.state + 1) % names_length], names[(self.state + 2) % names_length])
```

Or basically repeat the first two elements in the end of the list so you can get them by simply add 1 or 2

```
def state_to_text(self): 
    names = ["Kings", "Queens", "Jacks", "Jokers", "Masons", "Warriors", "Soldiers", "Kings", "Queens"] 
    return str(names[self.state + 1], names[self.state + 2])
```

Comment: Dude thank you, I failed to think about the option for the second solution. For anyone wondering I ended up using: return str((self.state + 1) % len(self.names)) + " " + str((self.state + 2) % len(self.names))

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add your offsets to the `self.state`. This won't change `self.state` since it's just an expression, not an assignment.

```
def state_to_text(self): 
    names = ["Kings", "Queens", "Jacks", "Jokers", "Masons", "Warriors", "Soldiers"]
    return str(names[self.state + 1], names[self.state + 2])
```

In order to make sure you don't walk off the end of the array, you might want to add an `if` statement that checks that `self.state` doesn't get set higher than `len(names) - 2`.

Comment: I can't do that because I need Soldiers to be able to get the 'enemies' of 'King' and 'Queens' -- I need to find a way to find a way to essentially loop back to the start of the loop